# Regex captures all occurrences but the last of certain characters

Tags: regex

I want to exclude common punctuation from my URL Regex detector when my clients type a sentence with a URL in it. A common scenario would be the URL `example.com?q=this` (which obviously needs to include the `?`) versus a sentence saying

> What do you think of example.com?

This expression suits my needs just fine:

`(?:https?\:\/\/)?(?:\w+\.)+\w{2,}(?:[?#/]\S*)?`

However it includes all punctuation at the end, so I am iterating through each match to find and use this captured group to exclude said punctuation:

`(.*?)[?,!.;:]+$`

However, I'm not sure how to leverage the "end of string" technique when scanning the entire block of text which may have multiple URLs. Was hoping there'd be a way to capture the right blocks from the get-go without the extra work.

Answer (score 0):

Just require non-whitespace after the punctuation instead of making it optional.

```
(?:https?\:\/\/)?(?:\w+\.)+\w{2,}(?:[?#\/]\S+)?
```

You will of course lose valid ending of URLs like example.com/ will become example.com but as far as I know there is no difference.

Comment: This still captures the trailing punctuation. It works for `example.com?` but not `example.com?a=foo?`